# Calva Error "LSP classpath lookup failed when running `lein with-profile +test,+dev classpath`. "

Tags: clojure, leiningen, vscode-calva

I would like to use vs code as development environment for clojure.

I'm opening [guestbook](https://github.com/rajcspsg/guestbook) project in vs code.

As soon as the project is opened in vs code I get error pop up.

```
LSP classpath lookup failed when running `lein with-profile +test,+dev classpath`. Some features may not work properly if ignored. Error: Cannot run program "lein" (in directory "/Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/clj-web-dev/c01/guestbook"): error=2, No such file or directory Choose an option:
```

[image: calva vs code error]

I'm also getting below details in VS code output -

```
Calva is utilizing cider-nrepl and clojure-lsp to create this VS Code experience.
  nREPL dependencies configured:
    nrepl: 1.0.0
    cider-nrepl: 0.28.5
    cider/piggieback: 0.5.3
  clojure-lsp version configured: latest

If you are new to Calva, please see: https://calva.io/getting-started/
  And please consider the command: **Calva: Fire up the Getting Started REPL**

Calva version used: v2.0.350
```

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon a similar error but with a different root cause.
In your case it appears that VS Code is unable to launch `lein` (which is the build tool for the specified project). Make sure [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) is installed and added to the `PATH`.

P.S. I've encountered a similar issue when clojure-lsp tried to calculate classpath for the project which have abandoned `project.clj` and `deps.edn` at the same time (as a result of migration from `lein` to `clojure tools`). Had to create a config file and specify appropriate ['classpath scan' option](https://clojure-lsp.io/settings/#classpath-scan).

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need in install clojure. Follow the instructions here:
https://clojure.org/guides/install_clojure

Comment: I already have clojure installed